# Cannot map value of object seen in console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering, javascript-objects, es6-map

My idea is to click on any of the buttons on the left navbar and whenever the name of the clicked button in the `logos` object matches any of the names in the `items` object within `projects`, then display those objects.

When I click on any of the buttons on the left, I transform that object's `active` property to `true` within the `logos` object. After I've filtered the values, I can see all of the correct values in the console, but I can't loop through them - with a `for` loop or a `map`. Oddly enough, when I write `filteredValues[0]` I am able to output that data to the screen but since I want multiple outputs for some of these clicked values, this is not an option. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

[image: These are the items I'm getting back when I console log them]
These are the items that I can't loop through but am getting back when I console log them

[image: These are my projects]

These are my projects

[image: These are my logos]

These are my logos

```
 const Homepage = () => {

  const {state} = useContext(Context)
  const {projects,logos} = state;

  return (
    <>
  <div className="container">

    <Language />

    <div className="homepage">
          {logos.map(logo => {

            let filteredValues;

            if(logo.active == true){
              filteredValues = Object.values(projects).filter(({items}) => Object.values(items).includes(logo.name))

              filteredValues.map((val) =>{
                console.log(val)
                  return(
                        <div>{val.title}</div>
                      )
                    }) //end of filteredValues.map
                } //end of if
              }) // end of logos.map
            }
    </div>
  </div>
  </>
)}
```

Comment: Is it an array or object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Array.map() would always return an Array of same length, irrespective of you return anything or not. If you do not return anything then
it would be a sparse Array with empty values.
Try returning only the array with the required data. Here I have just separated out the Logos logic in a separate variable.

```
render() {

    const Logos = (
        <div className="homepage">
            logos.reduce((acc, logo) => {
                if (logo.active) {
                    const filteredValues = Object.values(projects).filter(({items}) => Object.values(items).includes(logo.name));
                    Object.values(projects).forEach(({items}) => {
                        if (Object.values(items).includes(logo.name)) {
                            acc.push((<div>{val.title}</div>));
                        }
                    });
                }
                return acc
            }, [])
        </div>
    )

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Language />
            {Logos}
        // rest of the code
    )
}
```

Comment: I switched up the code a bit but you led me down the right path

`logos.reduce((acc, logo) => {
   if (logo.active) {
   Object.values(projects).forEach((proj) => {
         if (Object.values(proj.items).includes(logo.name)) {
            acc.push((<Project title={proj.title} routeName={proj.routeName} items={proj.items} description={proj.description}/>));
                          }
                        });
                }
                return acc
            }, [])`